# How to extract class text based on the previous class text value?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, conditional-statements

I am scraping various information about multiple houses and the information on each house is not similar. To be consistent, I seek to extract the information value based on the class label. For example, I have the following below:

```
property_info = section_content.find_all('div',{'class':'dc_blocks_2c'})
property_info
```

This outputs:

```
<div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Bedrooms:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">9 Bedroom(s)</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Baths:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">10 Full  &amp; 4 Half Bath(s)</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Garage(s):</div>
 <div class="dc_value">4 / Attached</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Stories:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">2</div>
 </div>,
:
:
:
```

To clarify my issue better: some houses don't have the `<div class="dc_label">Stories:</div>` while some other houses do.
If I do the following: `property_info = section_content.find_all('div',{'class':'dc_value'})` then yes I get all of the text value I seek however, the list size will not be the same for every house. My pseudocode is what I seek to do:

```
if dc_label.text LIKE 'Bedrooms'
    then bedroom_num == bedroom_dc_value
if dc_label.text LIKE 'Garage(s)'
    then garage_num == garage_dc_value
if dc_label.text LIKE 'Bath(s)' IS EMPTY:
    then bath_num == ""
:
:
ect,
```

Any pointers/advice will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the url you are trying to scrape, and also show us your actual code written up to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you like to store the information in a structured way e.g. `dict` you could use a generic approach to get all properties. *Provided that the property label to be used as the key occurs only once.*

In case you like to create a `dataframe` or `csv` based on the result, the missing properties will automatically be handled as `None`:

First collect label and value from you `ResultSet`:

```
dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'dc_blocks_2c'}))
```

Cause label ends with `:` we like to `strip()` that from our keys:

```
props = {k.strip(':'): v for (k, v) in props.items()}
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Bedrooms:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">9 Bedroom(s)</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Baths:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">10 Full  &amp; 4 Half Bath(s)</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Garage(s):</div>
 <div class="dc_value">4 / Attached</div>
 </div>,
 <div class="dc_blocks_2c">
 <div class="dc_label">Stories:</div>
 <div class="dc_value">2</div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

props = dict(e.stripped_strings for e in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'dc_blocks_2c'}))
props = {k.strip(':'): v for (k, v) in props.items()}
props
```

###### Output

```
{'Bedrooms': '9 Bedroom(s)',
 'Baths': '10 Full  & 4 Half Bath(s)',
 'Garage(s)': '4 / Attached',
 'Stories': '2'}
```